# How to ,measure the size of a defect in pixels in a image (automatically)?

Tags: matlab

So I have a digital image of a semiconductor where there is a defect which I manage to extract by using segmentation techniques like this :

```
fig1 = imread('figure1.png');
imshow(fig1);

title('Original image', 'FontSize', 18);
%Gray image
fig1Gray = rgb2gray(fig1);



%Binary image
BW1 = imbinarize(fig1Gray,0.5);
imshow(BW1);
title('Binary image', 'FontSize', 18);

sr = strel('square',5);

%Dilation image
dilated1 = imdilate(BW1,sr);
imshow(dilated1);
title('Dilated image', 'FontSize', 18);

minus1 = ~(BW1-dilated1);
imshow(minus1);
title('Minus image', 'FontSize', 18);
imshowpair(minus1,BW1,'montage');
```

How can I measure the size of the defected area in pixels?

**EDIT:** Image added
[image]

Comment: You forgot to post the image...

Comment: Now the image is added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [bwconncomp](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwconncomp.html) for clustering:

```
CC = bwconncomp(~BW1)
```

Returns the following structure:

```
CC = 

  struct with fields:

    Connectivity: 8
       ImageSize: [247 247]
      NumObjects: 1
    PixelIdxList: {[404×1 double]}
```

Assuming your pre-processing stages are correct, the size of the defected area is:

```
length(CC.PixelIdxList{1})
```

---

You can also use [regionprops](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html):

```
fig1 = imread('figure1.png');
fig1Gray = rgb2gray(fig1);
BW1 = imbinarize(fig1Gray,0.5);
stats = regionprops(~BW1, 'Area');
biggest_area = max([stats.Area]);
```

Result: biggest_area = 404

---

Marking the area in yellow color:

```
Y = im2uint8(cat(3, ones(size(BW1)), ones(size(BW1)), zeros(size(BW1))));
fig1(~cat(3, BW1, BW1, BW1)) = Y(~cat(3, BW1, BW1, BW1));
figure;imshow(fig1)
```

Output:
[image]

The white sounding also looks like a part of the defective region.
In case you need to include some of the sounding area, use `imdialte`:

```
BW2 = imdilate(~BW1, ones(5));fig1(cat(3, BW2, BW2, BW2)) = Y(cat(3, BW2, BW2, BW2));figure;imshow(fig1)
```

[image]

Comment: So this is the size of the defect only, not the whole image?

Comment: The total number of pixels in the whole image is `size(fig1,1)*size(fig1,2)` = 247*247 = 61009.

Comment: Yes, thank you for the additional information. First, I use dilation and then extracting the dilated image from the original one so I get the contour and I believe in this way I get the defected image. 
I need to apply the same code for two more similar pictures and it should work for all of them.

Comment: I also tried with erosion, opening and closing but then the object of interest got lost.

Comment: For including the white contour, you can try the following technique: `T = abs(fig1Gray - medfilt2(fig1Gray, [50, 50], 'symmetric'));imshow(imclose(imbinarize(uint8(T), 0.1), ones(3)));`